# SQL Book page index with auto overwrite

Tags: sql, postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I want to achieve something like a *Book pages*.

e.g:
I have a book with `100` pages, each of page has unique priority/page number, (1-100).

```
+-----+--------------------------------+------+
| id  |            content             | page |
+-----+--------------------------------+------+
| 1   | cover                          | 1    |
| 2   | prelude                        | 2    |
| ... | ...                            | ...  |
| 50  | and so he do rig a jig jig...  | 50   |
| 51  | and he come to the bus stop... | 51   |
| ... | ...                            | ...  |
| 100 | back-cover                     | 100  |
+-----+--------------------------------+------+
```

Let's imagine I insert a new page, but between page `50` and `51`. So the inserted page priority/page number is `51`.

And so, overwrite the upper page number, the "OLD" page 51-100 would be 52-101.

```
+-----+--------------------------------+------+
| id  |            content             | page |
+-----+--------------------------------+------+
| 1   | cover                          | 1    |
| 2   | prelude                        | 2    |
| ... | ...                            | ...  |
| 50  | and so he do rig a jig jig...  | 50   |
| 101 | this is a new page             | 51   |
| 51  | and he come to the bus stop... | 52   |
| ... | ...                            | ...  |
| 100 | back-cover                     | 101  |
+-----+--------------------------------+------+
```

I'm using PostgreSQL, TypeORM, TypeScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
--Updates the table and sets each page value to itself + 1
--Under conditions: the page number is the same as the inserted record but the
--content is different (the original record with that page number)
--Or the page number is greater than the page number of the inserted record    
UPDATE Table
SET [page] = [page] + 1
WHERE ([page] >= insertedPageNumber AND content <> insertedPageContent) OR [page] > insertedPageNumber
```

Comment: I got a trouble again...

UPDATE page SET "pageNumber" = "pageNumber" + 1 WHERE ("pageNumber" >= 1) OR "pageNumber" > 1

Key ("pageNumber")=(2) already exists.

Comment: I know because I set the col to unique
Is it possible to do it with UNIQUE?

Comment: @FransiscoWijaya If the page you are inserting is page 1, it should increment the current page 1 to page 2, then page 2 would go to page 3 and so on. I'm having trouble understanding what your issue is.

Comment: I can't insert in the middle of range.
if I insert to 3, it brokes the UNIQUE rule.

Comment: whatever, i simply just not to use UNIQUE.

Comment: @FransiscoWijaya How does it break a unique rule? The  id is the unique identity column is it not? The query I provided just changes the page value, which I believe is capable of change.

Comment: @FransiscoWijaya You could run my UPDATE query before doing the insert and then the page value would be different upon INSERT. Then you should be able to keep it as UNIQUE

Comment: The Unique is the [page] column.